# How can I set my DNS settings using the command-prompt or PS?

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns

Through the CLI (either cmd.exe or PowerShell) on Windows 7, how do I edit the TCP/IP DNS parameters for a specific network adapter?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/463096/change-dns-with-script/463110#463110

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[netsh.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785383.aspx)

```
netsh interface ip set dns name="Local Area Connection" source=static addr=none

netsh interface ip add dns name="Local Area Connection" addr=8.8.4.4 index=1
netsh interface ip add dns name="Local Area Connection" addr=8.8.8.8 index=2

netsh interface ip set dns name="Local Area Connection" source=dhcp
```

Comment: Might need to flush the dns too. ```ipconfig /flushdns```

Comment: Is "Ethernet" same with name="Local Area Connection"?

Answer (score 3):

Main thing: you can set first DNS as static entry. Next you can only **add**/**append** other DNS servers.  So, to set primary DNS server use something like this:

```
netsh interface ip set dns name="Local Area Connection" static 8.8.8.8
```

for adding/appending other DNS servers you have to use **add** option, something like this:

```
netsh interface ip add dns name="Local Area Connection" addr=8.8.4.4 index=2
```

Comment: Or to simplify the 2 statement: `netsh interface ip add dns "Local Area Connection" 8.8.4.4 2`

Answer (score 1):

There is a ton of information on managing DNS servers with Powershell, here is a great article from the [scripting guys:](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/09/13/manage-dns-in-a-windows-environment-by-using-powershell.aspx)

If your wanting to manage your own Local DNS settings on your workstation, you can use powershell to connect to WMI, and use the [DNS WMI classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682123%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).