# Specify DNS servers per SSID in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, dns, wifi-configuration, ssid

Is it possible to specify DNS servers per SSID in Windows 10?

At the moment, the DNS servers are pulled via DHCP from the AP that I am connected to. I would like that to happen only when I'm home, when I'm travelling or on other networks, I want to make use of third party DNS servers such as Cloudflare.  I know that this is scriptable but I wanted to see if there was a setting within Windows to do this without having to run a script each time I'm connected to a different SSID.

Is this something that's doable? Thanks!

Comment: It could be scripted. But please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I did see that it was scriptable but I wanted to know if there are any Windows settings that would allow me to specify that my laptop uses Cloudflare for all other networks other than my home network, which would pull down the DNS settings via DHCP.  I did see [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/weekend-scripter-modify-dns-settings-via-windows-powershell/) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/463096/change-dns-with-script) but I would rather not run a script every time.