# What parameters do I need for the "netsh int ip set dns" Windows command?

Tags: windows-7, networking, command-line, dns

[This article](https://www.wiknix.com/how-to-fix-dns-lookup-failed-error-in-chrome/) calls for CMD commands to fix an issue with DNS lookup. All the commands were successful up to these last two:

```
netsh int ip set dns
netsh winsock reset
```

When I try the first command, CMD asks for parameters. I couldn't decipher CMD's hints for proper syntax, so I googled. The best thing that came up was [this](https://superuser.com/questions/204046/how-can-i-set-my-dns-settings-using-the-command-prompt-or-ps) which includes lengthy commands like:

```
netsh interface ip set dns name="Local Area Connection" source=static addr=none

netsh interface ip add dns name="Local Area Connection" addr=8.8.4.4 index=1
netsh interface ip add dns name="Local Area Connection" addr=8.8.8.8 index=2

netsh interface ip set dns name="Local Area Connection" source=dhcp
```

I have no idea if the paramteres were designed for my problem so I fear running them. Microsoft documentation fails to mention my require commands (only netsh IPsec, not netsh IP)

I would like to perform the first two commands successfully but I have no idea which parameters to include.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry sometimes I forget :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **What parameters do I need for the “netsh int ip set dns” Windows command?**

You can use the `netsh int ipv4 set dns help` command line syntax to get **help** on the commands you are trying to run and explain the applicable argument parameters to pass to it.

In your particular instance you can pass the `name` parameter and its value for the name of the interface you are setting the DNS on, and the `addr` parameters and its value for the IP address of the DNS server it'll use for DNS.

```
C:\Users\User>netsh int ipv4 set dns help

Usage: set dnsservers [name=]<string> [source=]dhcp|static
             [[address=]<IP address>|none]
             [[register=]none|primary|both]
             [[validate=]yes|no]

Parameters:

  Tag            Value
  name         - The name or index of the interface.
  source       - One of the following values:
                 dhcp: Sets DHCP as the source for configuring DNS
                       servers for the specific interface.
                 static: Sets the source for configuring DNS servers
                         to local static configuration.
  address      - One of the following values:
                 <IP address>: An IP address for a DNS server.
                 none: Clears the list of DNS servers.
  register     - One of the following values:
                 none: Disables Dynamic DNS registration.
                 primary: Register under the primary DNS suffix only.
                 both: Register under both the primary DNS suffix, as
                       well as under the connection-specific suffix.
  validate     - Specifies whether validation of the DNS server setting
                 will be performed. The value is yes by default.

Remarks: Sets DNS server configuration to either DHCP or static mode. Only
         when source is 'static', is the 'addr' option also available for
         configuring a static list of DNS server IP addresses for the
         specified interface. If Validate switch is yes, then
         the newly set DNS server is validated.

Examples:

   set dnsservers name="Wired Ethernet Connection" source=dhcp
   set dnsservers "Wired Ethernet Connection" static 10.0.0.1 primary
```

Comment: How do you _"specify a list of DNS server IP addresses"_? I tried a comma-delimited list to no avail: `addr=9.9.9.9,192.168.0.123`

Comment: @RyanWheale I would look at the solution I provided here for a simple way to do this honestly https://superuser.com/questions/1625611/get-active-network-adapter-and-set-dns-via-powershell/1625641#1625641. If you can use PowerShell, these things are usually more robust. I've never tried setting more than one DNS address on an interface with the commands from this answer, but I have done it just fine with the commands from that answer. Hope you find it helpful but comment me there with questions.

Answer (score 2):

To follow up JUICED_IT's answer, the network name is likely "Ethernet", not "Local Area Connection". To find out the name you can do this:

```
netsh interface show interface
```

Which will show the name under the "Interface Name" column (shown here in bold):

```
Admin State    State          Type             Interface Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        Ethernet
```

Now you can change the primary dns (index=1), assuming that your interface is static (not using dhcp):

```
netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver "Ethernet" address=192.168.x.x index=1
```

`netsh winsock reset`, as the command states resets the winsock catalog to a clean slate.

> `c:\>netsh winsock reset /?`
>
> ```
>   Resets Winsock Catalog to a clean state.
>   All Winsock Layered Service Providers which were previously 
>   installed must be reinstalled.
>   This command does not affect Winsock Name Space Provider entries.
> ```