# Find Windows DNS info?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, windows-8, dns

It's possible to change the DNS server using Control Panel and cmd, but is there a file which contains the DNS IP addresses?

[image: Windows dialog to change DNS server configuration]

Can we manually modify the DNS IPs using a notepad or something?

Comment: Did you change it and search the registry for the value or your system? You could also try to use Sysinternals ProcMon to see what changes but why are you actually interested in this? Also note that while it might be possible to change the value that doesn't necessarily mean that it will be instantly picked up without triggering some form of refresh or similar.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1094099/what-parameters-do-i-need-for-the-netsh-int-ip-set-dns-windows-command has the syntax for a command to change it from the command line

Answer (score 0):

You can found it under HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces. 
Find the entry named **NameServer** , which stores the DNS info.
[image]