# Netsh interface ip set dns register

Tags: windows, network-adapter, netsh

One of the parameters of the command `Netsh interface ip set dns` is `register`. What is its purpouse? I do not understand the explanations given in the help. Which value is set to this parameter if I set the DNS configuration of a network adapter through the Windows GUI?

Command help:

```
C:\Users\User>netsh int ipv4 set dns help

Usage: set dnsservers [name=]<string> [source=]dhcp|static
             [[address=]<IP address>|none]
             [[register=]none|primary|both]
             [[validate=]yes|no]

Parameters:

  Tag            Value
  name         - The name or index of the interface.
  source       - One of the following values:
                 dhcp: Sets DHCP as the source for configuring DNS
                       servers for the specific interface.
                 static: Sets the source for configuring DNS servers
                         to local static configuration.
  address      - One of the following values:
                 <IP address>: An IP address for a DNS server.
                 none: Clears the list of DNS servers.
  register     - One of the following values:
                 none: Disables Dynamic DNS registration.
                 primary: Register under the primary DNS suffix only.
                 both: Register under both the primary DNS suffix, as
                       well as under the connection-specific suffix.
  validate     - Specifies whether validation of the DNS server setting
                 will be performed. The value is yes by default.

Remarks: Sets DNS server configuration to either DHCP or static mode. Only
         when source is 'static', is the 'addr' option also available for
         configuring a static list of DNS server IP addresses for the
         specified interface. If Validate switch is yes, then
         the newly set DNS server is validated.

Examples:

   set dnsservers name="Wired Ethernet Connection" source=dhcp
   set dnsservers "Wired Ethernet Connection" static 10.0.0.1 primary
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It adjusts the DNS values in the IPV4 properties for the specified interface.

```
netsh interface ipv4 set dnsserver "Ethernet" static address=192.168.1.1 register=primary
```

Sets this when viewed in Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network Connections:
[image]

See https://superuser.com/a/204059/576067 for more examples.

Comment: Is name="Local Area Connection" same with "Ethernet"?